# what does <a class="none"> really mean?

Tags: css, wordpress, class, wordpress-theming

Im not sure if anyone can help me with this but I came across this piece of code while modifying a theme for a wordpress. What is the effect of class="none" in this ? There is no css pointing to this class anywhere.

```
<a class="post-thumb none" id="thumb-165" href="" title="">
      <span class="no-img" style="width:90px;height:90px"></span>    
</a>
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: i cannot seem to find such a class using chrome developer tools

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If there is no class called "none" in the related stylesheet(s) and no in-line code affecting them, this is essentially a redundant class. However, it may be used by javascript somewhere so watch for that

Comment: Yes, it is commonplace for jQuery developers (given the ease of use of classes in selectors) to add classes to mark elements as suitable for certain things.

Answer (score 0):

It is used to put a space between lines in Wordpress. The "class="none" with a 
 works.